# Formatting "Kilo", "Mega", "Gig" data in numpy record array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot something which is in this csv format: timestamp, value. But the values are not real numbers but rather abbreviations of large values (k = 1000, M = 1000000 etc).

```
2012-02-24 09:07:01, 8.1M
2012-02-24 09:07:02, 64.8M
2012-02-24 09:07:03, 84.8M
2012-02-24 09:07:04, 84.8M
2012-02-24 09:07:05, 84.8M
2012-02-24 09:07:07, 84.8M
2012-02-24 09:07:08, 84.8M
2012-02-24 09:07:09, 84.8M
2012-02-24 09:07:10, 84.8M
```

I usually use numpy record array to store the csv using `matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec(infile)`. But works only if the values are not in abbreviated form. Is there an easy way to do this without actually my program reading each value, looking for 'M' to convert 84.8M to 84800000?

Comment: Why `84810000` and not `84800000`? Am I missing something or are you asking how to get more information out of a number than there is?

Comment: Well, you could simply change `M` with `e6`, etc. This would make that value a valid float.

Comment: @NiklasB. Sorry that was a typo! You are right, it should be 84800000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another possibility is the following conversion function:

```
conv = dict(zip('kMGT', (3, 6, 9, 12)))
def parse_number(value):
  if value[-1] in conv:
    value = '{}e{}'.format(value[:-1], conv[value[-1]])
  return float(value)
```

Example:

```
>>> parse_number('1337')
1337.0
>>> parse_number('8.1k')
8100.0
>>> parse_number('8.1M')
8100000.0
>>> parse_number('64.367G')
64367000000.0
```

Comment: I assume you'd use this along with the `converters` kwarg?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the function by Niklas B. in the **convertd** argument of csv2rec:

```
>>> data = mlab.csv2rec(infile, names=['datetime', 'values'],
...                     convertd={'values': parse_number})
>>> data
rec.array([(datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 24, 9, 7, 1), 8100000.0),
   (datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 24, 9, 7, 2), 64800000.0),
   (datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 24, 9, 7, 3), 84800000.0),
   (datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 24, 9, 7, 4), 84800000.0),
   (datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 24, 9, 7, 5), 84800000.0),
   (datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 24, 9, 7, 7), 84800000.0),
   (datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 24, 9, 7, 8), 84800000.0),
   (datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 24, 9, 7, 9), 84800000.0),
   (datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 24, 9, 7, 10), 84800000.0)], 
  dtype=[('datetime', '|O8'), ('values', '<f8')])
```